# User access control for particular page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to create a new blank page for a client's Drupal-6 based website. and it must have access only for users under custom created role-admin . We will put the page live when content is done. How can I assign page access only for a particular role?

I don't give User-1 login info to client. So, making unpublished is not a solution for me :|

Is there any module for my need? or any other solution?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Make the role only allowed to edit own pages in permissions. Go into authoring information on the page and set that user as the author.